# Is there a way to have a container fall back to a console if the process stops?

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile

Maybe I am approaching this the wrong way, but if I have a container that runs some program and I run it with "-d -it" it starts the program and I can attach to it to view the output.

But if I do ctrl+c the process stops and the container exits. Sometimes though I want the container to continue running so I can investigate. I'd like to set it to fall back to /bin/sh or /bin/bash or some console so it doesn't exit and I can poke around while it is still up.

Obviously I don't want this for a production container but when I'm deving it would be nice to switch this on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try: `CTRL-p` `CTRL-q`.

> You can detach from a container and leave it running using the CTRL-p CTRL-q key sequence.

https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/attach/#extended-description